# type mismatch on Network.Wai.Middleware

Tags: haskell

I am trying to follow [this post](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-15-making-a-website-with-haskell.html) to serve static files with scotty. So I have this small script:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Web.Scotty
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Static

import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "static")
  get "/:word" $ do
    beam <- param "word"
    html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

Running ghc yields the following error:

```
server.hs:9:16:
    Couldn't match type `Network.Wai.Internal.Request'
                  with `wai-1.4.0.1:Network.Wai.Request'
    Expected type: wai-1.4.0.1:Network.Wai.Middleware
      Actual type: Network.Wai.Middleware
    In the return type of a call of `staticPolicy'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "static")'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "static")
```

Now I don't understand how to interpret `wai-1.4.0.1:Network.Wai.Middleware` vs `Network.Wai.Middleware`. Is it a version issue? I tried checking the library installed, but I could not find any conflict.

What should I check to solve this?

**Edit**

Running `ghc-pkg list wai` gives me:

```
C:\perso\prog\haskell\orgmode\orgmodeserver\src\hs>ghc-pkg list wai
WARNING: there are broken packages.  Run 'ghc-pkg check' for more details.
C:/Program Files (x86)/Haskell Platform/2013.2.0.0\lib\package.conf.d:

C:\Users\sberg\AppData\Roaming\ghc\i386-mingw32-7.6.3\package.conf.d:
    wai-1.4.0.1
    wai-2.0.0
```

Running `ghc-pkg check` (skipping a bunch of warnings):

```
The following packages are broken, either because they have a problem
listed above, or because they depend on a broken package.
scion-browser-0.2.17
miamtime-0.0.0
TestYes-0.0.0
yesod-platform-1.2.2
yesod-1.2.1.1
yesod-auth-1.2.0.2
yesod-form-1.3.0.1
```

Comment: This does look like a version issue. What is the output of `ghc-pkg list wai`?

Comment: @user2407038 see my edit. Does it mean that I have 2 wai lib installed?

Comment: Precisely. There are probably a dozen different ways to fix this, but the simplest solution is to unregister all the broken packages, unregister both version of `wai` and install all the packages again, making sure you are not installing 2 versions of `wai`. Use the flag `--dry-run` to make sure `cabal install` isn't installing the old version. If it decides it needs 1.4 and can't use 2.0, you may have to use older versions of some packages.

Comment: @user2407038 thanks. I am trying this now.

Comment: @user2407038 I worked. I am not sure if I did not break a few other things, but I have learned something new today. If you care to copy/past your comment in an answer I will accept it. Otherwise I will write it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a dozen different ways to fix this, but the simplest solution is to unregister all the broken packages, unregister both version of wai and install all the packages again, making sure you are not installing 2 versions of wai. Use the flag --dry-run to make sure cabal install isn't installing the old version. If it decides it needs 1.4 and can't use 2.0, you may have to use older versions of some packages.